# keeping track of login cookies between multiple devices

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, mysqli

So I just just built/hacked together my first cookie verification formula, and seems to work all-right, but have realized that it does not accommodate for when a user logs in on multiple devices, as well as one tester reporting slowness(which I cannot directly attest to the cookies). I do recognize a few possible means to solving the multiple device issue, but as I have never really used cookies before, I would like some expert opinion on the **best** way to handle this. If anyone has any other advice for my methods, they would be greatly appreciated, and I will almost certainly implement them before adding this a the header of each page.

```
function rememberMe() {

    $cookie = isset($_COOKIE['rememberme']) ? $_COOKIE['rememberme'] : '';

    if ($cookie) {
          list ($username, $token, $mac) = explode(':', $cookie);
          if ($mac !== hash_hmac('sha256', $username . ':' . $token, XXXX)) {
               return false;
          }

          function fetchTokenByUsername($username) {
                    $host="";
                    $dbusername="xxxx";
                    $dbpassword="xxxx";
                    $database="xxxx";

                    global $mysqli;
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, token
                                              FROM cookielogin
                                              WHERE username=? //pull most recent cookie key from DB
                                              ORDER BY keyid DESC
                                              LIMIT 1");
                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
                    if (!$stmt) {
                                 header('Location: login.php');
                                 die();
                                 }
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($userjunk, $userToken);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    return $userToken;
             }

             function logUserIn($username) {
                    $host="";
                    $dbusername="xxxx";
                    $dbpassword="xxxx";
                    $database="xxxx";

                    global $mysqli;

                    $active=1;
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, username, password, gender, homelat, homelng, salt FROM users WHERE username=? AND active=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param('si', $username, $active);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $email, $xusername, $xpassword, $gender, $homelat, $homelng, $salt);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    if (!$stmt) {
                        header('Location: login.php');
                        die();
                    }
                    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
                    if ($numrows == 0) {
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
                        $_SESSION['error'] = ("Incorrect username and password combination, please try to log in again");
                        exit();
                    }
                    session_regenerate_id(); // set session information
                    $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['sess_email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $xusername;
                    $_SESSION['sess_gender'] = $gender;
                    $_SESSION['sess_homelat'] = $homelat;
                    $_SESSION['sess_homelng'] = $homelng;
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
              }

              function timingSafeCompare($userToken, $token) {
                    //removed for brevity (and pulled from a library, so I am confident in it's abilities)
                }

                $userToken = fetchTokenByUsername($username);
                if (timingSafeCompare($userToken, $token) === 0) {
                         logUserIn($username);
                         return true;
                }
           }
           else{
                   return false;
           }
    }

if ((isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) and $_SESSION['sess_username'] != '') ||(rememberMe()== true)):
```

as you can see, I only check the users cookie against the most recently stored cookie key in my database. This is where multiple devices are an issue. My though was I could pull up the last 5 cookie keys from the database, build an array, then check if theirs is in the array. This doesn't seem fool proof by any means though.  I also supposed I could save each cookie with an ip address, but this would obviously fail under a VPN. 
As for now, I only store the cookie key with the username, time of last use, and an auto increment column.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you're allowing multiple devices, you might as well just re-use the same cookieid for every login, if that login occurs within a certain period. e.g. log in from 2 devices within 10 minutes, they both get the same ID and then there's no problem. but how would you be able to detect between legitimate user A on one device, and bad-user-B-who-stole-A's-account on the other device?

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea. If I understand correctly, though, that would seem to be a problem with any method of allowing both devices to be logged in. I am pretty sure this is common practice though?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the cookie's token as a condition in your select statement:

```
<?php
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, token
                                      FROM cookielogin
                                      WHERE username=? //pull most recent cookie key from DB
                                      AND token=?
                                      ORDER BY keyid DESC
                                      LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $token);
```

That allows you to use different cookies for each device.

Comment: Thanks, I like it. I would like to know a bit more about the security in this. I would seem that I'd no longer need to validate the likeness of the two tokens.

Comment: @ambe5960 True, because you're essentially doing that "validation" at the time of the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @ambe5960 You just want to make sure you actually get a result.

Comment: Do you have to prune the cookielogin table often?

Comment: I stopped working on this project, but yea, presumably would have to. Was gonna setup a cron job to do so, but never got around to doing it